# Vector iterating, error of type with the scanf

Tags: arrays, c, vector

The error I get with every type I tried (character, float and integer): warning: passing argument 2 of `leerVectorDeEnteros` makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion].

I have the code in a library, and when I try to use it, the only function that really works (still with the warning though), is the integer one, the one of floats and characters doesn't work at all.
[That's the error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln7MB.png)

```
void leerVectorDeEnteros(char mensaje[], int vec[], int cant) {
   printf("%s\n", mensaje);
   for(int i = 0; i < cant; i++){
        printf("[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &(vec[i]));
  }
}

void leerVectorDeFloats(char mensaje[], float vec[], int cant) {
   printf("%s\n", mensaje);
   for(int i = 0; i < cant; i++){
        printf("[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &vec[i]);
   }
}

void leerVectorDeCaracteres(char mensaje[], char vec[], int cant) {
   printf("%s\n", mensaje);
   for(int i = 0; i < cant; i++){
        printf("[%d]: ", i);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &vec[i]);
   }
 }
```

Feel free if i made a mistake with the question to tell me that, i'm new in this world =|.

This is the code i'm trying to execute, and the error is in there.

```
void main() {
  char vec[3];
  leerVectorDeCaracteres("Ingrese los valores del vector:",vec[3],3);
  mostrarVectorDeCaracteres(vec[3],3);
}
```

Comment: (But it looks like you are passing `vec[3]` as the 2nd argument, where you should just have `vec`.)

Comment: ...which is why the function does not work. There is *no point* running code with warnings such as this.

Comment: Don't use `fflush(stdin);`, it's a UB.  You can put a space before the %c to eat the '\n' left in the keyboard buffer.  `scanf(" %c", &vec[i]);`  the main function returns an int

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.